# Searching an external URL for files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, url, dom

I am building a page that needs to be able to get a all the file links on a webpage and add them to a dropdown list. Original it was the script was supposed to be on the same page as the files but now it  needs to search an external. This is what I used before the change

```js
 <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             var arr = [];
             var filenames = [];
             var alt_var;
             var baseURL = "www.fakeurl.com"
             $('.ms-vb-icon').find('a').each(function(){
          var temp = $(this).attr('href')
          $(this).find('img').each(function(){
          alt_var = $(this).attr('alt');
          });
          if(temp.indexOf('.csv') != -1){arr.push(temp); filenames.push(alt_var);}
         });
          for(i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
          {
          var x = document.createElement('li');
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          var t = document.createTextNode(" " + filenames[i]);
          var fullURL = baseURL + arr[i];
          a.setAttribute('href',"#");
          a.setAttribute('class', "glyphicon glyphicon-file");
          a.setAttribute('id', baseURL + arr[i]);
            a.setAttribute('onclick', "drawChart(this.id)");
          a.appendChild(t);
          x.appendChild(a);
            document.getElementById("dropdownfiles").appendChild(x);
          }                      
         });    
      </script>
```

How can I change this to search an external url. (PS new to Javascript)

Comment: Will the "external" URL be on the same domain?

Comment: Most likely but its going to be on a company sharepoint site so I was hoping it could connect to all the different sharepoint domains

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way but you could add a hidden iframe on the page and then search in there.

css:

```
.externalSearcher iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="externalSearcher"></div>
```

js:

```
$('.externalSearcher').append('<iframe src="' + externalLink + '"></iframe>');
$('.externalSearcher').find('a').each(function () {
    //do what you want with the link
});
```